# Set process name in shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have something like this

```
./myProcess.sh &
```

So I run it in background. When I put ps the proccess name is "bash".

```
16282 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
```

Is there any way of starting a process with a name? When I put the command ps, I wanna see the proccess name (and the PID, and other information), not "bash".

Thank you so much

Comment: As an aside, using a `.sh` extension for executable shell scripts (as opposed to shell libraries intended to be sourced rather than executed) is bad form: It means that if you ever rewrite that executable into a non-shell language, you'll either need to modify all callers or live with a misleading name. (Also, if it's bash, ksh, or another shell other than POSIX sh, a `.sh` extension gives a misleading/incorrect signal about which interpreters it's compatible with).

Answer (score 3):

The script name is in bash's command-line, it's just `ps` doesn't display it by default. You can use `ps -f` to print the full argument list.

```
$ ps -f
jkugelm+  28798   9819  0 16:17 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./myProcess.sh
```

Comment: It shows me this user 18307 16282  0 23:45 pts/5    00:00:00 bash

Comment: How did you start the process?

Comment: Same as you, `./myProcess.sh &`.

Comment: It does not work, keep showing "bash" in CMD section